# Mac apache problem

Tags: apache, macos

I run apache on a mac. My document root folder is /Library/WebServer/Documents. When I create new subfolder under Documents folder I can't load images from that subfolder.

My html file under /Library/WebServer/Documents/test is:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<img src="http://localhost/test/angry.gif"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The angry.gif file is placed under test/ folder. I also perform chmod -R 777 test/ but doesn't seem efficient.

Any suggestion?

Andrej

Comment: Did you try to access directly to `angry.gif` with the url ttp://localhost/test/angry.gif ?

Comment: I take it that if you put an HTML file and an image file in in your subfolder `/Library/WebServer/Documents/test`, then you can view the HTML file in your browser but not the image file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using localhost doesn't generally work out very well. Really what you want to do is something like this:

```
<img src="angry.gif"/>
```

If its in the same folder it will work out fine.

Hope this helps,
Christian Stewart

Comment: I modified code according to your suggestion but doesn't work. I think it should be an apache issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I try to access angry.gif directly  with the url http://localhost/test/angry.gif, it doesn't work